# Overwriting the ID of one HTML element with the text of another

Tags: javascript, jquery, webflow

I use CMS Webflow (CMS Feature of a website builder) to build HTML elements that repeat themselves. Webflow duplicates these automatically. Unfortunately, it also duplicates the IDs of the element itself and all nested elements, making them non-unique. For various reasons, I have to use this feature.

Now I use an embedded script to overwrite the ID of a particular nested HTML Element (Heading) with the innerText of another (also Heading). Both elements sit inside the mentioned element that is automatically being duplicated.

The second headings text (the reference heading whose text I want to grab) is automatically filled by the CMS feature and therefore unique.

But when I log the new Id of the first heading to the console (which was overwritten with the innerText of the second heading) it's just empty. In the following code I've added comments (// alternatively:) with alternative code lines, which make the code work, but not as desired.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(event) { 

    let elementToBeChanged = $(event.target).next("#changeMyId");
    let elementWithReferenceText = $(event.target).parent().next("#useMeToChangeId");
    // alternatively: let elementWithReferenceText = $(this).find("#useMeToChangeId");

    let newId = elementWithReferenceText.text();
    // alternatively: let newId = Math.floor(Math.random()*6) // to verify that generating a unique ID each time the element gets duplicated is possible (it is)

    console.log(newId) // to compare with console.log(elementToBeChanged.id) if ID was changed correctly
    elementToBeChanged.id = newId;
    console.log(elementToBeChanged.id); // to check if ID was changed 
});
</script>
```

I think the problem with the code is that does not select the correct second heading. 
Oddly with this jQuery selector it works:

```
let elementWithReferenceText = $(this).find("#useMeToChangeId");
```

But obviously always overwrites the ID with the same value every time since it's not a relative path.

Unfortunately, the relative path does not work, the console.log(newId) logs just empty to the console (I assume this line is the problem):

```
let elementWithReferenceText = $(event.target).parent().next("#useMeToChangeId");
```

I used the following to verify that generating a unique ID each time the element gets duplicated is possible (it is)

```
let newId = Math.floor(Math.random()*6)
```

[image: HTML Structure:]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you query for all elements with the ID and change them as desired. Your script tag would have to be after all the elements that have been duplicated

```js
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("#duplicate"))
  .forEach((el, index) => {
    if (index > 0) {
      el.id = el.id + "-" + index;
    }
  });

Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("p"))
  .forEach((el, i) => {
    console.log(`Element index ${i}, id: ${el.id}`)
  });
```

```html
<p id="duplicate">

</p>

<p id="duplicate">

</p>

<p id="duplicate">

</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

`let elementWithReferenceText = $(this).find("#useMeToChangeId");`

This just finds the element with the id *useMeToChangeId* in `$(this)`, which, in `$(document).ready()`, is (I assume) the document. That makes it almost identical to just calling `$('#useMeToChangeId');`. And of course that will work if the element with that ID exists on the page.

You *could* check if `let elementWithReferenceText = $(event.target).parent().next("#useMeToChangeId");` actually does something. Perhaps the parent of `$(event.target)` is not followed by an element with the ID "useMeToChangeId". Have you checked if `elementWithReferenceText` contains a value? E.g.

```
console.log(elementWithReferenceText);
```

after you define `elementWithReferenceText`?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I did log: `elementWithReferenceText` to the console, it prints this: `w.fn.init [prevObject: w.fn.init(0)]
length: 0
prevObject: w.fn.init [prevObject: w.fn.init]
__proto__: Object(0)`and logs nothing for: `elementWithReferenceText.text();`. Which also leads me to believe that  `$(event.target).parent().next("#useMeToChangeId");` does not select the right element. But judging from theHTML structure it should, and I don't know how to identify what element it picks instead.

Comment: Are you sure that that element is the first next sibling of the one that is selected? Because that is what `next()` selects. Perhaps try doing `next()` without the `#useMeToChangeId` selector and see the output? Your console log says that something was selected by jQuery, but it has a length of 0, so actually nothing was selected. Perhaps the next element is not #useMeToChangeId?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the id of an element with Webflow CMS data in a custom HTML embed block.

Within a collection item, add an embed, and then "+ Add Field" button will allow you to use your CMS data within the code.

Webflow embed image:
[image: webflow embed image]

Comment: Your picture only contains textual information, which is more appreciated in textform here.

Comment: I used the screen capture because it is in the context of the Webflow user interface and depicts how to use dynamic data in that view. Also, my reputation only allows for me to include the image as a link, but someone with sufficient rep can suggest the edit to embed, and I can then allow the suggestion.

Comment: If you are convinced that your picture provides additional insight then keep it. But please provide the text it shows as text. You do not need any privilege for that. The part where the picture shows something useful could use some explanation, maybe the content of your post. Please [edit] to add it to the answer, instead of hiding it in a comment.

Comment: @orgreeno thanks so much for the suggestion, I solved it some time ago with the forEach loop suggested by Juan.